# call and end ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call ajax function such

```
 $(save_Data()).ajaxStop(function()
     {
        new_Form(code);
     }


 function save_Data()
   {
      // here send data to php and save it
   }
```

Now, I call another ajax function such

```
  $(get_Data()).ajaxStop(function()
       { 
             // doing some thing
       }


  function get_Data()
   {
      $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert_Stock.php',
            data: { insert_Data : inserted_Data },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data)
                {
                   // doing some thing such call another function to control on form
                }
        });
   }
```

When I call save_Data function already new_Form function execute, after that when I call get_Data function the new_Form function execute automatically.
Why new_Form function execute?

Comment: Because you're calling the function inside ajaxStop...

Comment: ok , how i can call it ?? @BhojendraNepal

Comment: ajaxStop is called only once....

Comment: what is something rather than ajaxStop to tell me ajax call is Finished ?? @BhojendraNepal

Comment: I hope you need then method...

Comment: Sorry, I could be not getting you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you this is what you want.

```
function doSomething(){
  //your code here if success
}

function doSomethingElse(){
  //your code here if error
}

function finallyDoSomethingElse(){
  //your code here no matter what is the result of post
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert_Stock.php',
    data: { insert_Data : inserted_Data },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: doSomething,
    error: doSomethingElse,
    complete: finallyDoSomethingElse
});
```